# Исключить дублирование кода в функциях с разной константностью

Tags: c++, рефакторинг

Рассмотрим такой код:

```
struct B {};
struct D1 : B {};
struct D2 : B {};

#define get if (s) return d1; else return d2;

volatile bool s;

struct C {
    const B& f() const { get }
    B& f() { get } 
private:
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
};
```

Здесь видно, что разные версии `f()` должны возвращать один и тот же объект (в одном случае - константный, в другом - нет), основываясь на некоторой логике выбора, которая может быть достаточно сложной. В примере для исключения дублирования кода этой логики использована макроподстановка через `#define`.

Можно ли избежать дублирования кода в разных версиях `f()` не прибегая к услугам препроцессора?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема дублирования кода из-за соображений константности обычно встречается в двух вариантах:

1. На уровне отдельных функций: когда есть две функции с одинаковой реализацией, отличающиеся лишь константностью входных типов (в т.ч., как частный случай, константностью `*this` в методе класса) и соответствующей константностью возвращаемого значения.

   В языке С одной из известных идиом для решения этой проблемы является написание одной-единственной функции, которая решает поставленную задачу в рамках соблюдения константности входных данных, а затем просто безусловно снимает константность с возвращаемого значения (см., например, стандартную функцию `strstr`). В данном случае предполагается, что вызывающий код, будучи в курсе ситуации с константностью данных, "по-джентельменски" вернет "потерянную" в процессе вызова функции константность на место.

   В языке С++ этот подход технически тоже применим, но его использовать не принято. Точнее, традиционная С++ идиома, основанная внутренне фактически на том же самом подходе, внешне реализуется с небольшим отличием: полноценная реализация предоставляется для константной версии функции, а над ней надстраивается вторая - неконстантная - версия той же функции. Последняя реализуется через константную путем снятия константности с возвращаемого значения

   ```
   const return_type *foo(const input_type *argument)
   {
     ...
   }

   return_type *foo(input_type *argument)
   {
     return const_cast<return_type *>(foo(const_cast<const input_type *>(argument));
   }
   ```

   Вот именно этот подход прекрасно подойдет в вашем случае.
2. На уровне отдельных классов: кода надо реализовать два класса, которые фактически идентичны с точки зрения исходного кода, а отличаются лишь внешней константностью обрабатываемых данных. Хороший пример: константная и неконстантная версия класса контейнерного итератора.

   В такой ситуации один из жизнеспособных подходов - реализация общей функциональности в виде шаблонного класса, параметризованного необходимым количеством типов (в простейшем случае - одним), и реализация требуемых финальных классов через специализации этого шаблона. Что-то вроде

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class list 
   {
     template <typename U> class iterator_impl {
       ...
     };

     typedef iterator_impl<T> iterator;
     typedef iterator_impl<const T> const_iterator;
     ...
   };
   ```

**P.S.** Ваш собственный ответ, использующий шаблонную функцию - это фактически адаптирование вышеприведенного *второго* подхода к *первой* ситуации. Работать, без сомнения, будет, однако именно в такой ситуации банальный вариант с `const_cast`, как мне кажется, выглядит проще и уместнее.

Answer (score 8):

Можно написать что-то вроде следующего

```
struct C {
    const B& f() const { if (s) return d1; else return d2; }
    B& f() { return const_cast<B &>( const_cast<const C *>( this )->f() ); } 
private:
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
};
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

struct B {};
struct D1 : B {};
struct D2 : B {};

bool s;

struct C {
    const B& f() const 
    {
        std::cout << "const B & f() const" << std::endl;
        if (s) return d1; else return d2; 
    }
    B& f() 
    { 
        std::cout << "B & f()" << std::endl;
        return const_cast<B &>( const_cast<const C *>( this )->f() ); 
    } 
private:
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
};

int main() 
{
    C c1;
    c1.f();

    std::cout << std::endl;

    const C c2;
    c2.f();

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
B & f()
const B & f() const

const B & f() const
```

Answer (score 5):

Придумал вариант с шаблонной дружественной функцией:

```
template<class R, class T>
R& g(T* t);

struct C {
    const B& f() const { return g<const B&>(this); }
    B& f() { return g<B&>(this); }
private:
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    template<class R, class T> 
    friend R& g(T* t);
};

template<class R, class T>
R& g(T* t) {
    if (s) return t->d1; else return t->d2;
}
```

Или можно вовсе перенести в класс:

```
struct C {
    const B& f() const;
    B& f();
private:
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    template<class R, class T> 
    static R& g(T* t) {
        if (s) return t->d1; else return t->d2;
    }
};

const B& C::f() const { return g<const B&>(this); }

B& C::f() { return g<B&>(this); }
```

А т.к тип `R` по сути может быть выведен из факта наличия константности в `T`, то этот тип можно вовсе убрать из шаблона:

```
template<class T> 
static std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>, const B&, B&> g(T* t) {
    if (s) return t->d1; else return t->d2;
}
```

Т.о. необходимость явно указывать тип при вызове `g` отпадает:

```
const B& C::f() const { return g(this); }

B& C::f() { return g(this); }
```

Answer (score 4):

Очевидный вариант:

```
class A {
    bool flag;
    int a;
    int b;

public:
    int& get() { return flag ? a : b; }
    const int& get() const { return ((A*)this)->get(); }
};
```

Пример:

```
int main()
{
    A a {};
    const A ca {};
    static_assert(std::is_same<int&, decltype(a.get())>::value, "!!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<const int&, decltype(ca.get())>::value, "!!");
}
```

Comment: тут по сути такой же **const_cast**, только теперь он спрятан за сишным приведением

Comment: @mymedia точно. Задумался и перепутал с обратным приведением. Поправил ответ

Comment: Вызывать константную функцию из неконстантной - нормальная практика. А вот когда наоборот - можно схватить UB от подобных приведений.